# problemas al insertar en una bd

Tags: mysql, python, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 tablas en mi base de datos una de ellas es tarjetas y la otra tipo tarjetas básicamente después de normalizar la tabla tarjetas se quedo con una fk tipo que enlaza a la pk tipo tarjeta, luego inserte datos en esta ultima como esta su estructura mas abajo luego quise insertar varios datos en la tabla tarjetas y me dio error de

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prueba`.`tarjetas`, CONSTRAINT `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`))

básicamente por la clave foránea que tiene pero yo no veo donde esta el error me podrían dar una mano? mas abajo mis SQLs

Aqui el de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE `tarjetas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_expedicion` date NOT NULL,
  `fecha_vencimento` date NOT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `saldo_actual` decimal(12,0) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `numero` (`uid`)
);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `tipo_tarjeta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

);
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE `tarjetas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) 
  REFERENCES `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`);
```

---

Inserción de datos:

```
INSERT INTO `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`, `descripcion`) VALUES
(1, 'Regular'),
(2, 'Estudiante'),
(3, 'Discapacitado'),
(4, 'Adulto Mayor');
```

> aqui radica el problema

```
INSERT INTO `tarjetas` 
(`id`, `uid`, `fecha_expedicion`, `fecha_vencimento`, `estado`, `saldo_actual`, `tipo`) 
VALUES
(NULL, 'AE3D6C9A', '2017-08-09', '2018-08-09', 0, 50000, 1),
(NULL, '7E5B6C9A', '2017-08-09', '2018-08-09', 1, 350000, 1),
(NULL, "0EEE6B9A", "2017-08-09", "2018-08-09", "1", 0, 1)
```

curiosamente si inserto todo este esquema me funciona a la perfección pero si inserto varios registros mas a la vez vuelve a saltar ese error
Obs. si inserto un registro a la vez no tengo ese problema

me seria de mucha utilidad una mano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está aquí:

```
ALTER TABLE `tarjetas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) 
  REFERENCES `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`);
```

Estás indicando que la columna que es llave foránea es el `id` (columna auto-incremental de la tabla `tarjetas`), cuando la tabla pasa de `4` registros empezará a darte problemas, porque ya crearía registros huérfanos. La relación debe ser entre la columna `tipo` de la tabla `tarjetas` y la columna `id` de la tabla `tipo_tarjeta`.

La restricción entonces debería ser escrita así:

```
ALTER TABLE `tarjetas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`tipo`) 
  REFERENCES `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`);
```

> Dado que ya la restricción errónea existe, conviene borrarla del
>   siguiente modo:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE `tarjetas`
>   DROP FOREIGN KEY  `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK`
> ```
>
> Y luego crearla de nuevo correctamente:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE `tarjetas`
>   ADD CONSTRAINT `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`tipo`) 
>   REFERENCES `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`);
> ```

Comment: exactamente... justo después de mandar mi preguntar y de jugar un rato en fiddle lo encontre... error de novato... gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que probé tu código con el siguiente código y es funcional

```
CREATE TABLE `tipo_tarjeta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

);

CREATE TABLE `tarjetas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_expedicion` date NOT NULL,
  `fecha_vencimento` date NOT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `saldo_actual` decimal(12,0) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `numero` (`uid`)
);

ALTER TABLE `tarjetas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) 
  REFERENCES `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`);

INSERT INTO `tipo_tarjeta` (`id`, `descripcion`) VALUES
(1, 'Regular'),
(2, 'Estudiante'),
(3, 'Discapacitado'),
(4, 'Adulto Mayor');

INSERT INTO `tarjetas` 
(`id`, `uid`, `fecha_expedicion`, `fecha_vencimento`, `estado`, `saldo_actual`, `tipo`) 
VALUES
(NULL, 'AE3D6C9A', '2017-08-09', '2018-08-09', 0, 50000, 1),
(NULL, '7E5B6C9A', '2017-08-09', '2018-08-09', 1, 350000, 1),
(NULL, "0EEE6B9A", "2017-08-09", "2018-08-09", "1", 0, 1);
```

> Lo que veo como problema es que tratas de añadir una `FK` a una tabla
>   que aún no existe; es decir le quieres añadir la `fk`
>   `tarjetas_tipo_tarjeta_FK` a la tabla tarjetas que estas declarando
>   primero, pero esa fk HACE REFERENCIA a la tabla tipo_tarjeta que justo
>   en ese momento no existe.
>
> Es decir las tablas que no tienen llaves foráneas van primero en tu
>   declaración de tu BD y las tablas que tienen llaves foráneas van justo
>   después

Comment: Alfredo, inserta unos cuantos valores más en `tarjetas` y vendrá el problema :-)

Comment: gracias por la observación @A.Cedano lo hice y comprobe el fallo no puse bien atención en ese detalle